# What is Stitch?

Tags: character, lilo-and-stitch

Stitch is a cute and fluffy alien and is the titular character of Disney's *Lilo and Stitch.* But what type of lifeforms are Stitch and the other experiments created by the mad scientist Jumba?

Though it may be simple to say they are organic (they are illegal genetic experiments, after all), I remember Jumba rewiring an experiment in one episode of *Lilo and Stitch*, and he uses a screwdriver to do so.

Also, it's said that Stitch can think faster than a supercomputer and Jumba is constantly referring to 'programming'.

Finally, the movie *Stitch Has A Glitch*, where Stitch is going crazy because 'his molecules aren't charged enough'.

So what are they? Genetic experiments or cyborgs?

Comment: I don't know that we've been given enough information to answer this.  But my best guess is that they are organic, but built from the ground up.  Rather than using electronics and metal to build his creations, Jumba used organic molecules and cells.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stitch_(Lilo_%26_Stitch)) Stich is:

> An illegally-made, genetically-engineered, extraterrestrial lifeform
>   resembling a blue koala

As such, they we can say Stitch is genetic, and not a cyborg.

The "programming" could relate to the genetic programming, as in DNA, which controls aspects of behaviour.  When thinking faster than a super computer, you need to factor in that for some tasks, humans are faster than a computer.  It's just that computers are great for calculations, so usually seem faster.

I don't have enough information to comment on all experiments, but Stitch is not a cyborg.

Comment: "programming" could also be mental conditioning